# Django schedule: Difference between event.get_occurrence() and event.get_occurrences()?

Tags: django, events, methods, schedule

Based on [django-schedule](https://github.com/bartekgorny/django-schedule). I can't find the guy who made it.

Pardon me if I'm missing something, but I've been trying to get an events occurrences, preferably for a given day.

When I use event.get_occurrence(date), it always returns nothing. But when I use event.get_occurrences(before_date, after_date), suddenly the occurrences on the previously attempted date show up.

Why won't this work with just one datetime object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This difference is probably in the actual design of these two methods. Frankly, `get_occurrence` is rather flawed, in general. A method like this should always return *something*, even if it's just `None`, but there's scenarios where it doesn't return at all. Namely, if your event doesn't have an rrule, and the date you passed `get_occurrence` isn't the same as your event's `start`, then no value is returned.

There's not really anything that can be done about that. It's just flawed code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above comment especially in the case when the event doesn't return and occurrence, the following snippet below can force the retrieval of an occurrence especially when you are sure that it exists

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def custom_get_occurrence(event,start_date):
    occurrence = event.get_occurrence(start_date)
    if occurrence is None:
        occurrences = event.get_occurrences(start_date, start_date+relative_delta(months=3)
        result = filter(lambda x: x.start==start_date,occurrences)
        occurence = result[0]
```

The above code resolves issue that might occur when the default get_occurrence doesn't return a result.